# Passing in array of different sized array tf.placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to pass in an array filled with multidimensional arrays of different shapes. What is the best way of passing this into a placeholder to be used in sess.run?

I currently have the following code which is not surprising producing an error.

```
arr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=None, name='arr_placeholder')
a1, a2, a3, ts = sess.run([model.a1, model.a2, model.a3, train_step], feed_dict={
      x_input: sub_batch[0],
      y_input: sub_batch[1],
      arr_input: arr})
arr = [a1, a2, a3]
```

Which is producing the error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Regardless, there is still an issue with the 'arr_placeholder' shape.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Giving more details may help us get a better understanding about your true needs and come up some solutions. If your arrays have the same number of dimensions, it is possible to construct a SparseTensor to contain all of them.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related with the feed_dict input, input should be numpy array not list/placeholder.

```
a1, a2, a3, ts = sess.run([model.a1, model.a2, model.a3, train_step], feed_dict={
  x_input: np.asarray(sub_batch[0]),
  y_input: np.asarray(sub_batch[1]),
  arr_input: <this should be numpy array, not placeholder>})
```